# AJax Loading Animation Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, loading

Please I can't get this script to work

```
function Display_Load()
{
$("#loading").fadeIn(900,0);
$("#loading").html('<img src="../images/loadinganimation.gif" />');

}
//Hide Loading Image
function Hide_Load()
{
$("#loading").fadeOut('slow');
};

//Pagination Click
$("#pagination-flickr li").click(function(){
Display_Load();
});

-------
<ul class="pagination-flickr">
<li>some data to click</li>
</ul>

<div id="loading"></div>
```

Comment: It would be awfully helpful if you would describe what it's supposed to do, what goes wrong with it in its current state, and what sorts of things you've found from your own debugging.

Comment: Loading data but not showing loading gif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a guess: you want the fade-in to start only after the image is available?  Try this:

```
function Display_Load()
{
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = function() {
    $("#loading").fadeIn(900);
    $("#loading").html('<img src="../images/loadinganimation.gif" />');
  };
  img.src = '../images/loadinganimation.gif';
}
```

If the issue is that you want the image to show up *before* the content is loaded, then the problem is that the call to "fadeIn" will cause the `<div>` to be made invisible before it's made visible. In other words, the first thing "fadeIn" does is to hide the element so that it can actually "fade in" to view.

Comment: Well what would that error be?  You're not being very helpful here.

Answer (score 2):

Your click handler is ref and id `#pagination-flickr` while your `<ul/>` is a class of `.pagination-flickr`

```
<ul class="pagination-flickr">
  <li>some data to click</li>
</ul>

$(".pagination-flickr li").click(function(){
  Display_Load();
});
```

**Code example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/eKdV5/1/).**